# How to get this output

Tags: linux, bash

I want to prinf like this; I want a any command producing this output

```
124.156.1.1
124.156.1.2
124.156.1.3
124.156.2.1
124.156.2.2
124.156.2.3
124.156.3.1
124.156.3.2
```

and so on.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: Could you expand on the "and so on" bit?

Comment: I need command to get output like this 124.156.1.1 to 124.156.255.255

Comment: This might help: [IP range generator script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35681157/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
printf '%s\n' 124.156.{1..255}.{1..255}
```